# what is the next code mean, the 'lambda request' and the '**kwargs: {}',i have never see this

Tags: python

```
def validate(request, *args, **kwargs):
    form_class = kwargs.pop('form_class')
    extra_args_func = kwargs.pop('callback', lambda request, *args, **kwargs: {})
```

thanks

---

```
a={'a':'aaa','b':'bbb'}
b=a.pop('a',lambda x,y:x)
print a
```

i know dict.pop('a'),but i don't know dict.pop('a',func)
what is the use of 'func‘ in here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression:

```
lambda request, *args, **kwargs: {}
```

builds an anonymous function which must be called with at least one argument (which, if named, must be named `request`) and can be called with any number of positional and named arguments: when called, it ignores all the arguments and returns a new empty dictionary.

The code snippet:

```
a={'a':'aaa','b':'bbb'}
b=a.pop('a',lambda x,y:x)
print a
```

prints `{'b': 'bbb'}` (which is also the value `a` stays bound this after the snippet executes) and bings the string `'aaa'` to name `b`.  The second argument to the `.pop` method plays no role in this case: it's only used when the first argument is **not** found as a key in the dictionary on which the method is called (in which case, `.pop`'s second argument would be the "default value" returned by the call to `.pop`, without any alteration to the dictionary).  In this case, `'a'` is indeed found at that time as a key in dictionary `a`, and therefore it's removed from that dictionary, and the corresponding value, string `'aaa'`, is returned by the call to `.pop` (whence it gets then bound to name `b`).

Comment: Wow, I never knew lambda functions where allowed to do that!

Answer (score 0):

That is a "[lambda function](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-forms)". It's a short way of expressing a function that's declared inline. It looks like this:

```
lambda arg1,arg2,...: expression
```

and is the equivalent of a nameless function that would look like this:

```
def some_nameless_function(arg1,arg2,...):
    return expression
```

So, the code you have there,

```
def validate(request, *args, **kwargs):
    form_class = kwargs.pop('form_class')
    extra_args_func = kwargs.pop('callback', lambda request, *args, **kwargs: {})
```

is equivalent to a function that looks like this:

```
def nameless_function(request, *args, **kwargs):
    return {}

def validate(request, *args, **kwargs):
    form_class = kwargs.pop('form_class')
    extra_args_func = kwargs.pop('callback', nameless_function)
```

Comment: thanks,and i know dict.pop('a'),but i don't know dict.pop('a',func)

what is that mean.

Comment: The second argument is a default value that is returned if there's nothing available to be popped. It doesn't necessarily have to be a function - it can be any value (in this case, it's a function because the things normally being popped are also functions - it's a dict of functions).

Answer (score 0):

What it's doing is pop off a callback function from the kwargs dict, or if that isn't set, it creates a lambda function that does nothing (returns an empty dict). The `request, *args, **kwargs` part is presumably the "signature" of the callback function.